# Vector error message and how to insert an object into a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `Room` class and it has this constructor:

```
Room::Room(string a, int b, int c, string d)
```

And in my main function I do:

```
vector<Room> room;
sale.push_back("aaa", 1, 2, "ccc");
```

It gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Room, std::allocator<Room> >::push_back(const char [4])’

note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Room, _Alloc = std::allocator<Room>]
```

I don't understand this error. How can I add a new room object into the vector?

Comment: Removed cpp tag; this question is not about the preprocessor.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know whats the difference between cpp and c++. I will be more careful in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
std::vector<Room> rooms;
room.push_back(Room("aaa", 1, 2, "ccc"));
```

Comment: Best answer. Next, I need to find out, how to edit particular informmation of particular Room.

Comment: If your `Room` has a public member `roomNumber`, you can access them like `rooms[0].roomNumber`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `push_back` function as you do, just because the `push_back` function does not replaces the constructor. Here is the solution:

```
vector<Room> rooms;
Room ins("aaa",1,2,"ccc");
rooms.push_back(ins);
```